# Javascript clears a variable after there is no further reference it

Tags: javascript, performance

It is said, javascript clears a variable from memory after its being referenced last.

just for the sake of this question  i created a **JS file for DEMO** with only one variable;

```
//file start 

//variable defined
var a=["Hello"]

//refenence to that variable
alert(a[0]);

//
//file end
```

no further reference to that variable, so i expect javascript to clear varaible `'a'`

Now i just ran this page and then opened firebug and ran this code

```
alert(a[0]);
```

Now this alerts the value of variable, If the statement "Javascript clears a variable after  there is no further reference it" is true how come alert() shows its value.

Is it because all variable defined in global context become properties of window object, and since even after the execution file window objects exist so does it properties.

Comment: Yes, since it is global in scope, it is kept throughout the page lifetime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course the variable HAS to be kept around in this example - after all, you keep the ENVIRONMENT it has been defined in around. As long as you COULD still access it is has to be kept, so if you can make this test and it ever fails - the JS interpreter is "kaputt".

Do this instead:

```
(function () {
  var a = 1;
}());

// and NOW, at THIS point there is nothing any more referencing "a"
```

Of course, from out "here" you cannot test that - you'd have to look at the internal memory structures of the JS interpreter/compiler (today in the days of V8 it's more like a "interpiler" or "compreter" aynway).

In addition though, like all garbage collecting (GC) languages, the memory is not freed immediately but depending on GC strategy used by the particular implementation of Javascript, which also takes current memory usage and demand into account. GC is a costly operation and is delayed, if possible, and/or run when it does not take away CPU resources from the real app.

By the way, slight variation:

```
(function () {
  var a = 1;
  //empty function assigned to global namespace,
  //in browsers "window" is the global object
  window.example_function = function () {};
}());
```

In THIS example the result is the same as in yours: as long as you view that page the memory for "a" is NEVER released: the function assigned to property example_function of the global object still exists, so all of the environment is was defined in has to be kept! Only after

```
delete window.example_function
```

which deletes that property - which in the end is a pointer to the (empty) function expression - from the global object, could variable "a" be released. Also note that "a" is not even used by that function, see Google and search for "lexical scoping", one of the most defining properties of the Javascript language.

And even more fun:

Had I written

```
//define a variable in global namespace
var example_function;

(function () {
  var a = 1;
  //empty function assigned to global namespace,
  //in browsers "window" is the global object
  example_function = function () {};
}());
```

I could not use "delete" to remove it, in fact I could not ever release it. That's because in the first example example_function becomes a new property of the global **object** (emphasis), while in this last example it is a variable, and "delete" works with object properties only. (I used "windows.example_function" in the earlier example, but without the "window." it would have been just the same, example_function would have been created as property in the global object. Only the "var" statement creates variables.)

Comment: Love the scoping.  Nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it because all variable defined in global context become properties of window object, and since even after the execution file window objects exist so does it properties.

Yes. You would either have to close the window, or explicitly remove `a` from the window properties.

Answer (score 2):

A side effect of your script is that there's a property name "a" defined in the global object ( window ), so there is actually still a global reference to a.

```
(function()
{
  var a = 12;
  alert(a);
})();
```

If we wrap the declaration of a in self-executing function like here, a will be inaccessible after the function has exited.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, although you can mitigate this behavior by declaring and acting on your variables within the scope of a function:

```
( function myfunc(a){
  var b = 100;
  alert(a); // 200
  alert(b); // 100
}(200));

alert(a); // undefined
alert(b); // undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Referencing a variable does not mean using it in some manner. As long as there is at least one reference to the variable which can still be accessed, it has to be kept in memory.

Looking at your example, the following line has no effect on whether the variable gets cleared or not. Even if `a` wasn't being used anywhere, it would still have been kept intact.

```
//refenence to that variable
alert(a[0]);
```

Although an object may be created inside a function, its lifetime may extend beyond the function itself. The only thing to remember is whether there are still any valid references to the object in question. Consider this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/W8mp6/),

```
(function() {
    var a = ["Hello"];
    var copy = a;
    a = null;

    setTimeout(function() {
        // a: null, copy: ["Hello"]
        console.log("a: %o, copy: %o", a, copy);
    }, 2000);
})();
```

The variable `a` is created inside an anonymous function, and another variable `copy` is referencing it. `a` is set to `null` right after, but we still have 1 reference to it from `copy`. Then we create a timeout which makes another reference to the same variable. Now even though this anonymous function will go out of scope after it executes the `setTimeout`, we still left 1 reference to it in the timeout function. So this `copy` variable will still be intact when the timeout function is run.